# show hidden contents after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that if I select an option in a select tag some contents will display. the problem is if I submit the form and there is an error, the contents is now hidden.

I read related topics and it says about local storage, but I don't know how to implement it.

This is my sample script. Thanks

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loc_type1').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '11')
      {
        $("#services11").show();
        $("#services13").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value ==  '13') {
        $("#services13").show();
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value ==  '14') {
        $("#services14").show();
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services13").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services13").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah but if there is an error in validation, the page remain and just display all required fields..

Comment: yes, because I know the problem is on the script.. http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/ check this one. its the same.

Comment: add your relevant html and css too.

Answer (score 0):

Your script only runs when the value change, you may need to run it on page load too.

```
// Make it a function
function updateVisibleServices(){
    if ( this.value == '11'){
        $("#services11").show();
        $("#services13").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
    }
    else if ( this.value ==  '13') {
        $("#services13").show();
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
    }
    else if ( this.value ==  '14') {
        $("#services14").show();
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services13").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#services11").hide();
        $("#services13").hide();
        $("#services14").hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add the event
    $('#loc_type1').on('change', updateVisibleServices);
    // and also call it on page load
    updateVisibleServices();
});
```